# Multivariable Calculus problem: studying continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable, and $\varphi'(x)$ continuous;
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
>
> $\begin{equation*}
>      f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
>                 \frac{\varphi(y) - \varphi(x)}{y-x}         & x \neq y\\
>                 \varphi'(y)               & x = y\\
>             \end{cases} \end{equation*} $
>
> Determine in which points $f$ is continuous.

If $x \neq y$, $f$ is clearly continuous because is sum and product of continuous functions.

If $x = y$, the problem is to check if: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,x_0)} f(x,y) = \varphi'(x_0)$.

Let $A= \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=y \}$, it's obvious that    $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,x_0)} f|_A(x,y) = \varphi'(x_0)$, because $\varphi'$ is continuous. But what about $f|_{A^C}$? I tried unsuccessfully to use the definition of $\varphi'(x_0)$ to solve the limit. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to use
$$
\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)}{y-x} - \varphi'(x_0) = \bigg( \frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x_0)}{y-x_0} - \varphi'(x_0) \bigg) \frac{y-x_0}{y-x} + \bigg( \frac{\varphi(x_0)-\varphi(x)}{x_0-x} - \varphi'(x_0) \bigg) \frac{x_0-x}{y-x},
$$
but this doesn't seem to work well when $x$ and $y$ are much closer together than they are to $x_0$....

Comment: @NoahOlander How could $f$ not be continuous on the diagonal? $\varphi'$ is given to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. For $x\ne y$, note that there exists $z_{(x,y)}\in\mathbb{R}$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)}{y-x} = \varphi'(z_{(x,y)})$. Since $z_{(x,y)}$ is between $x$ and $y$, it follows that $|z_{(x,y)}-x_0|\le\max(|x-x_0|,|y-x_0|)$. As $(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,x_0)$, we have $|x-x_0|\rightarrow 0$ and $|y-x_0|\rightarrow 0$, so $|z_{(x,y)}-x_0|\rightarrow 0$, and by continuity $\varphi'(z_{(x,y)})\rightarrow \varphi'(x_0)$ as well. This shows that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,x_0),x\ne y}{f(x,y)} = \varphi'(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in all cases,

$$f(x,y) = \int_0^1\varphi'(x +(y-x)t)\, dt.$$

Because $\varphi'$ is continuous, it's straightforward to show that integral is continuous, i.e., $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Hi, can you explain how do you get this result?

Comment: It's the FTC and a change of variable.